# Hibernate: Foreign key must have same number of columns as primary key

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many, hibernate-onetomany

I have the following two classes (this is simplified a bit):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = 'DETAILS')
class Details
{
  // Properties
  @Id @Column(name = 'ID') Integer id
  @Id @Column(name = 'ID2') String secondaryId
  @Id @Column(name = 'FIRST_NAME') String firstName
  @Id @Column(name = 'LAST_NAME') String lastName
  @Id @Column(name = 'CHANGE_TYPE') String changeType
}


@Entity
@Table(name = 'USERS')
class User
{
  // Properties
  @Id @Column(name = 'ID') Integer id
  @Column(name = 'ID2') String secondaryId
  @OneToMany @JoinColumn(name = 'ID') List<Details> details
}
```

The User TABLE contains the user's ID information and references the DETAILS table that contains the actual details about the user.  The Details class has a composite key while the User class has just one key field and its this key field that is used to join to get all the columns from the DETAILS table.

Unfortunately this results in a "Foreign key must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key" error.  Obviously I'm missing something here.  If I were to use all the keys of the Details class to join, then it would result in a one to one mapping not a one to many mapping.  How do I set this up so that the User class can contain all the Details objects that have the corresponding ID?

Comment: Why don't you just use the `ID` field as primary key in your `Details` class? And how could a `User` have more than one `Details` field (more than one firstname/lastname)?

Comment: My understanding is that the primary key needs to identify a unique row ... in the DETAILS table all fields are required to identify a unique row.  It's a history table that contains multiple rows per ID.

Comment: Normalize your schema: it's a huge mess. Use just ID as ID in Details, add a USER_ID column to the details table, which is a FK to USER.ID, and use JoinColumn(name = 'USER_ID') on the User.details field.

Comment: It's a legacy database ... and yes it's a huge mess ... but nothing I can do about it ... have to work with it as is :(